# Screen recording with Python, PyQt6, QtWebEngineWidgets and Mac OSX Sonoma

Tags: python, pyqt6, macos-sonoma

I have a problem with screen recording with Python, PyQt6 and QtWebEngineWidgets with Mac OSx Sonoma operating system.

With a QtWebEngineWidgets instance I start a browser, start the recording by pressing a button equally I stop it with a button.

The problem I am experiencing is that if with a timer I run a 20 second recording, the video produced, even if it works produces a video that lasts less than 1 second.

I have tried many approaches, but have not been able to solve this problem. I have an idea that it depends on how python is handled by the operating system.

I did a test, having all the frames that are generated recorded. For 20 seconds of recording, 32 frames were recorded. And this is very strange. I also tried to force the recording by making it so that for each second 20 or 24 frames were recorded but no luck.

To start the recording from the parent script I use:

```
    def start_recording(self):
        applicazione_log(f"BROWSER: Start recording") 
        self.record_button.setText("STOP RECORDING AND SAVE ACQUISITION")
        self.recording = True
        self.recording_task = VideoRecorder(self.unique_code)
        self.recording_thread = RecordingThread(self.recording_task)
        self.recording_thread.start()

    def stop_recording(self):
        applicazione_log(f"BROWSER: Stop recording") 
        self.recording = False
        self.record_button.setText("START RECORDING")
        if self.recording_task:
            self.recording_task.stop()
            self.recording_thread.quit()
            self.recording_thread.wait()
```

The script that records the screen is this:

```
import os
import ffmpeg
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss
import pyautogui
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
import time

from .monitoraggio_applicazione import applicazione_log

class VideoRecorder(QObject):
    frameAcquired = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, unique_code):
        super().__init__()
        self.running = True
        self.last_frame_time = 0
        self.frame_count = 0
        self.width, self.height = pyautogui.size()

        applicazione_log(f"pyautogui: width = {str(self.width)} width = {str(self.height)}")

        self.script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.parent_directory = os.path.dirname(self.script_directory)
        self.folder_documents = 'documents'
        self.folder_documents_path = os.path.join(self.parent_directory, self.folder_documents, unique_code)

        self.filename = os.path.join(self.folder_documents_path, "recorded_video.mp4")

        # Buffer per i frame
        self.buffer_size = 30
        self.buffer = []
        
        self.frame_rate = 24
        self.frame_duration = 1 / self.frame_rate

        try:
            self.video_stream = (
                ffmpeg.input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='bgr24', s=f'{self.width}x{self.height}', r=self.frame_rate)
                .output(self.filename, pix_fmt='yuv420p', vcodec='libx264', crf=20)
                .run_async(pipe_stdin=True, pipe_stdout=True, pipe_stderr=True)
            )

        except Exception as e:
            applicazione_log(f"Errore durante la configurazione di ffmpeg: {str(e)}")

    def stop(self):
        try:
            self.running = False
            self.video_stream.stdin.close()
            self.video_stream.wait()  
        except Exception as e:
            if "write to closed file" in str(e):
                applicazione_log(f"Errore di scrittura su file chiuso: {str(e)}")
            else:
                raise e

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        with mss() as sct:
            while self.running:
                try:
                    frame_filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f'frame_{int(time.time() * 1000)}.png')
                    screenshot = sct.shot(output=frame_filename)

                    frame = cv2.imread(frame_filename)

                    self.buffer.append((frame, time.perf_counter()))

                    if len(self.buffer) > self.buffer_size:
                        self.buffer.pop(0)

                    if len(self.buffer) > 0:
                        frame, timestamp = self.buffer.pop(0)
                        self.video_stream.stdin.write(frame.tobytes('C'))

                except Exception as e:
                    applicazione_log(f"Errore durante l'acquisizione e l'elaborazione dei frame: {str(e)}")

        self.video_stream.stdin.close()
        self.video_stream.wait()

class RecordingThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, video_recorder):
        super().__init__()
        self.video_recorder = video_recorder

    def run(self):
        self.video_recorder.run()
```

How come I can't get the sync between recording time and duration of the created video?

Comment: Are you sure that all the images are created and ffmpeg is correctly receiving (and processing) the data stream? Note that saving every image isn't very effective: every frame needs to be compressed, saved, read and decompressed. As far as I can see from the mss docs, you can easily grab the screen as raw image data, which seems much more efficient. Also note that having two separated objects for the same purpose (the QThread and the video recorder) is a bit pointless, especially if you use the thread like that (using a standard QThread with `moveToThread()` and `started` is more appropriate).

Comment: I rewrote the script like this [ScriptPython] (https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/idigt6mdqsop5uzyym07t/base-video-thread.py?rlkey=hcwr04izfwlz9sqbkbgqimmo1&dl=0).  I incorporated the recording of the video into the script that runs the browser. however, I found that if the desktop has a resolution of width = 3840 width = 2160 inevitably synchrony is lost in the recorded video file and 20 seconds or so becomes, in this circumstance, 4 seconds.